# how to create six items tabbar without third party library in swift?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

How to create six items tabbar like FaceBook without third party library? I have try to use third party library, but it can't do the effect I want. Is it any information I can study to make a six items tabbar?
Thank you.

Comment: Facebooks "tab bar" is most definitely a custom view, not the default tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible if you have more than 4 tab bars then More button is displayed, from Apple documentation:

> You can also use the delegate to monitor changes to the tab bar that are made by the More navigation controller, which is described in more detail in The More Navigation Controller.
>
> The More Navigation Controller
> The tab bar has limited space for displaying your custom items. If you **add six or more custom view** controllers to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller displays only the **first four items** plus the standard **More item on the tab bar**. Tapping the More item brings up a standard interface for selecting the remaining items.

More on:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller?language=objc#1653016

Comment: Yes, I know that original tab bar can only have five tab item. I want to know how to create a customize tab bar by myself